# Trying to run a whole module or multiple subs in a row from a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of subs like below in a single module:

```
Sub RowHeight()
    Rows("1:100000").RowHeight = 14
End Sub
Sub DeleteCol()
    Columns(1).Delete
End Sub

Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 4000
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Left(Cells(iCntr, 1), 5) <> "Total" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to run all of them in a row. When I try to add a macro to a button I see each step individually. How do I run them in a row?

Thanks!

Comment: Just make one "master" sub that calls the 3 individual ones.

Comment: When you do `MsgBox "Hi!"`, you invoke a procedure (function) named `MsgBox`. If you have a `DoSomething` procedure, you invoke it by writing `DoSomething` as an instruction. So, to invoke `sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria`, you can write `sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria` as an instruction. Suggestion: remove these underscores and stick to `PascalCase`, like you have with `RowHeight`... also `RowHeight` should probably be `SetActiveSheetRowHeight`, and `Rows` should be explicitly qualified with `ActiveSheet`, or `Me`, if it's in a worksheet module's code-behind.